# setVisible(true/false) error JFrame

Tags: java, swing, error-handling, jframe

So, I have a problem. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. I'll give you the code.

```
public void initialize2(){

    txtWaaropGokken = new JTextField();
    txtWaaropGokken.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    txtWaaropGokken.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtWaaropGokken.setText("Waar wil je op gokken?");
    txtWaaropGokken.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtWaaropGokken);
    txtWaaropGokken.setColumns(10);
    txtWaaropGokken.setEditable(false);

    JButton ChansesSimples = new JButton("Chanses Simples");
    ChansesSimples.setBounds(50, 65, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(ChansesSimples);
    ChansesSimples.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



            Random getal = new Random();
            int nummer;

            nummer=getal.nextInt(37); 

            txtHetBalletjeRolt = new JTextField();
            txtHetBalletjeRolt.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
            txtHetBalletjeRolt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            txtHetBalletjeRolt.setText("Het balletje is nu aan het rollen.");
            txtHetBalletjeRolt.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 32);
            frame.getContentPane().add(txtHetBalletjeRolt);
            txtHetBalletjeRolt.setColumns(10);
            txtHetBalletjeRolt.setEditable(false);

            ChansesSimples.setVisible(false); 
            Douzaines.setVisible(false);   \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            Colonne.setVisible(false);   \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            TransversaleSimple.setVisible(false); \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            Carre.setVisible(false);    \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            TransversalePlein.setVisible(false); \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            Cheval.setVisible(false);   \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            Plein.setVisible(false);   \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR
            Cheval.setVisible(false);   \\HERE I DO GET THE ERROR






            if(nummer == 1 || nummer == 3 || nummer == 5 || nummer == 7 || nummer == 9 || nummer == 12 || nummer == 14 || nummer == 16 || nummer == 18 || nummer == 19 || nummer == 21 || nummer == 23 || nummer == 25 || nummer == 27 || nummer == 30 || nummer == 32 || nummer == 34 || nummer == 36){    

                txtRoodGewonnen = new JTextField();
                txtRoodGewonnen.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
                txtRoodGewonnen.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                txtRoodGewonnen.setText("Gefeliciteerd! " + nummer + " is een rood nummer. Je hebt gewonnen!");
                txtRoodGewonnen.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 32);
                frame.getContentPane().add(txtRoodGewonnen);
                txtRoodGewonnen.setColumns(10);
                txtRoodGewonnen.setEditable(false);

                bedrag = bedrag + inzet * 1;

            }
            else{

                txtRoodVerloren = new JTextField();
                txtRoodVerloren.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
                txtRoodVerloren.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                txtRoodVerloren.setText(nummer + " is geen rood nummer. Je hebt verloren.");
                txtRoodVerloren.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 32);
                frame.getContentPane().add(txtRoodVerloren);
                txtRoodVerloren.setColumns(10);
                txtRoodVerloren.setEditable(false);

                bedrag = bedrag - inzet;


            }
            txtBedrag = new JTextField();
            txtBedrag.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
            txtBedrag.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            txtBedrag.setText("Je hebt nu " + bedrag + " euro.");
            txtBedrag.setBounds(10, 50, 414, 32);
            frame.getContentPane().add(txtBedrag);
            txtBedrag.setColumns(10);
            txtBedrag.setEditable(false);           
        }
    });

    JButton Douzaines = new JButton("Douzaines");
    Douzaines.setBounds(50, 105, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Douzaines);
    Douzaines.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });

    JButton Colonne = new JButton("Colonne");
    Colonne.setBounds(50, 145, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Colonne);
    Colonne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });

    JButton TransversaleSimple = new JButton("Transversale Simple");
    TransversaleSimple.setBounds(50, 185, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(TransversaleSimple);
    TransversaleSimple.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });

    JButton Carre = new JButton("Carré");
    Carre.setBounds(240, 65, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Carre);
    Carre.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });

    JButton TransversalePlein = new JButton("Transversale Plein");
    TransversalePlein.setBounds(240, 105, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(TransversalePlein);
    TransversalePlein.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });

    JButton Cheval = new JButton("Cheval");
    Cheval.setBounds(240, 145, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Cheval);
    Cheval.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });

    JButton Plein = new JButton("Plein");
    Plein.setBounds(240, 185, 155, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Plein);
    Plein.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            ChansesSimples.setVisible(false);    \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            Douzaines.setVisible(false);      \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            Colonne.setVisible(false);     \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            TransversaleSimple.setVisible(false); \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            Carre.setVisible(false);     \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            TransversalePlein.setVisible(false); \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            Cheval.setVisible(false);     \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            Plein.setVisible(false);     \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
            Cheval.setVisible(false);     \\HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR


        }
    });

}
```

The problem is that if the program has 'gone through' the JButton and if I then setVisible(false). It works. As you can see in the Plein JButton, I dont get any errors with that code. But in the  Chanses Simples JButton I can only let the button itself dissapear, if I dont want to get any errors. Of course I want the player the option to choose the first button. Any ideas?

This is the error code I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Frame1$3.actionPerformed(Frame1.java:182)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: are you initiating JFrame ?

Comment: By posting long code you are limiting number of people willing to help you. Consider simplifying your example and post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The way to fix such an error is easy: you read the stack trace, notice that the exception is a NullPointerException thrown from line 182 of Frame1.java, thus go to that line and ask yourself what could be null at that line. Using a debugger can help. Then you either fix the code to make sure that what is null is not, because it shouldn't be, or you fix the code by adding an `if` test checking if it's null before accessing one of its members. We have no idea what line 182 is in the posted wall of code, so we won't bother guessing.

Comment: Yes I'm initiating JFrame and you're right I'll post another question simplifying my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you shared, the button `Douzaines` (and the other related buttons) are used before they are declared:

```
Douzaines.setVisible(false);   // HERE I DO GET THE ERROR

// [...]

JButton Douzaines = new JButton("Douzaines");

// [...]

Douzaines.setVisible(false);      // HERE I DONT GET AN ERROR
```